# How to pick precedents and descendents rows on the basis of search string.- X

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm not new to Excel VBA but not an expert too. I'm in strange problem, someone plz help me I'm not able to think anymore.

My Excel Story:
I have some 40,000 rows in a spreadsheet. rows are in the pattern mentioned as below:

> row1) Source >  AppName1
>
> row2) Destination > corresponding value1
>
> row3) Destination > corresponding value2
>
> row4) Source >  AppName2
>
> row5) Destination > corresponding value3
>
> row6) Source >  AppName3
>
> row7) Destination > corresponding value1

Now if search by AppName let's be AppName1 then row2 and row3 should be copied to next sheet along with row1.
If I search for Value1 then it should get row1, row2, row3 row7 and row6 should be copied to next sheet. That means search strings precedents and descendent's rows should be copied to next sheet.

I cannot provide the sample sheet as my reputation points are less than 10.

Is there anyone who can guide and assist me I have spent my 3 days in this but not got any result.
I have a very critical schedule for preparing this inventory sheet I was doing it manually and it was taking 5-6days to do manually. I thought of automizing it but got stuck.

Here is my code that is not working:

```
Sub GenerateInventory()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
Set r1 = Cells(2, 8)
For i = 2 To nLastRow Step 1
If InStr(Cells(i, 6), "CMRI") <> 0 Then
Set r1 = Union(r1, Cells(i, 1))
End If
Next
r1.EntireRow.Select
r1.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("MS4Inventory").Select
Cells(100, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Error.Description

End Sub
```

This code is not upto the mark still in WIP.

Comment: What have you tried during these 3 days? Let us know, else we can't help you correct it...

Comment: Your example is rather difficult to understand. Please show us a sample of your sheet, and format it properly e.g. as `code` to get a fixed-width font.

Comment: You don't need 10 reputation to format your example properly. Just write a sample of your sheet as text, format it as `code`, and align the rows and columns properly using spaces etc. I still don't understand what your sheet looks like. Does cell A2 really contain the text `"Destination > corresponding value1"`?

Answer (score 0):

Your example data and requirements are difficult to understand.

I've modified your code a little, which may help you to progress.
If you can post a snippet of your data and the required result we can progress further

```
Sub GenerateInventory()
    Dim r As Range, r1 As Range, rMS4Inventory As Range
    Dim nLastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, shMS4Inventory As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set shMS4Inventory = wb.Worksheets("MS4Inventory")

    Set r = sh.UsedRange
    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    Set r1 = sh.Cells(2, 8)
    For i = 2 To nLastRow Step 1
        If InStr(sh.Cells(i, 6), "CMRI") <> 0 Then
            Set r1 = Union(r1, sh.Cells(i, 1))
        End If
    Next
    Set rMS4Inventory = shMS4Inventory.Cells(100, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    r1.EntireRow.Copy rMS4Inventory
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Resume
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Error.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

before going to the coding, let's grab the problem ....

you want to search for anything in the sheet, and return the three rows that belong to the "paragraph" where your search landed

Under the assumption that ALL paragraphs are TRIPLES, all the rows that mark the beginning of a "paragraph" have the same property: rownumber modulo 3 has the same constant value. So in whatever rownumber your search lands, you need to go back until rownumber modulo 3 gets equal your constant value. Having arrived there, you play out 3 rows - and stop

now coding should become pretty simple .... you fire a search or place the cursor "somewhere" by other means, and fire the `Sub Grab()`

```
Sub Grab3Rows()
Dim Idx As Long
    Idx = Selection.Row

    'find start of paragraph
    Do While Idx Mod 3 <> 2 ' change this constant as per your sheet
        Idx = Idx - 1
    Loop

    'select the 3 cells at the start of paragraph
    Selection.Offset(Idx - Selection.Row, 0).Resize(3, 1).Select

    'do the rest
End Sub
```

Under the assumption that paragraphs are n-tuples AND contain the string "Source" at the first line, you can do something similar: Whereever your search lands, you go back row by row until you arrive at a row containing string "Source", from there you play out rows until you again reach a row containing "Source"

```
Sub GrabByTextString()
Dim Idx As Long
    Idx = Selection.Row

    'find start of paragraph
    Do While Left(Selection.Offset(Idx - Selection.Row, 0), 6) <> "Source"
        Idx = Idx - 1
    Loop

    'select the the start of paragraph
    Selection.Offset(Idx - Selection.Row, 0).Select

    'expand selection until we reach next paragraph start
    Idx = 1

    Do While Left(Selection(1, 1).Offset(Idx, 0), 6) <> "Source"
        Idx = Idx + 1
        Selection.Resize(Idx, 1).Select
    Loop

    'do the rest
End Sub
```